# How do I want to access the path contained in the <script> tag selenium pytthon?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I want to access the path contained in the  tag selenium pytthon?

This is what I did, it didn't work.

```
action=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[14]/script[34]/div/div/input').send_keys('./_220703_112705.mp4')
```

```
<script id="TEMPLATE_GROUP_INFO_STRUCTURE" type="text/template"><button type="button" class="MdBtn01Close02"><%= COMMON_CLOSE %></button>
        <h1 class="MdHide"><%= BUDDY_GROUP_EDIT %></h1>
        <div class="MdBox04">
            <div class="MdCMN09ImgEdit">
                <input type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" class="mdCMN09ImgInput" style="background-image: url({{thumbnailImage}})" data-picture-path="{{groupInfo.picturePath}}"
                       title="<%= BUDDY_GROUP_EDIT %>">
                <input type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" class="MdIcoEdit01" title="<%= BUDDY_GROUP_EDIT %>">
            </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: Update the question with the parent element of the `<script>` element.

Comment: chrome-extension://ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/index.html

Comment: I'm trying to add a video to this extension.